# Can I have domain.com/blog in a different server than domain.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dns, heroku

Instead of having blog.domain.com, I'd like to have domain.com/blog. Is it possible to host domain.com on Heroku (for example) and domain.com/blog in another server?

I want to do this mostly for SEO reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to achieve that, but I don't think it's a good idea. Better make a subdomain - blog.domain.com

SEO is usually treated too serious, but, in fact, it won't give you significant improvement. Remember - content is the king.

Comment: Won't google see my site as 2 different domains? I read it here: http://www.nine.com.mt/blog/index.php/2011/02/blog-domain-com-or-domain-comblog/

Comment: Probably it will, but that's not the point. - 1. Google constantly updates its PageRank algorithm and taking any detailed assumptions about its work isn't well founded. 2. Due to the social nature (often linked) of the blog it is very problable, that it will quickly outperform your main site in Google or, at least, become equal. 3. Visitors coming from Google are less valuable than visitors coming from, for example, other blogs.